# how does the jquery resultview on Airbnb Search Page work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im really interested in airBNB search page, im trying to fiddle around with the code on firebug and see how it works, on the [AirBNB Search Page](http://www.airbnb.com/search#modified=true)

on the right hand top corner, the user can choose between three views they want the results to be displayed List, Photo and map.

im trying to see the JavaScript that does the transformation from List(default) to the photo view,

i know that when the user clicks the photo button, a

> .photo_view CSS Class

is being added, but i just don't know where thats being done on the jquery  side.

was wondering if anyone can help, Thanks :))

Comment: yes i know, but im trying to point out the library being used. thanks for the extra tip!!

Comment: If you're just asking how the code adds a class to an element, that's just a manipulation of the "className" property, which is a space-separated list of class names (in the form of a single overall string, not an array, in other words).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at their code but the idea is to use jquery so that you can dynamically toggle css classes.

For example, imagine you use the following css classes for the "list view":

```
.list{
width:400px;
height:100px;
}
.list img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

and the following for the "photo view"

```
.photo{
width:250px;
height:250px;
}
.photo img{
width:230px;
height:200px;
}
```

Using jquery you can easily switch the .list with the .photo class and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

1. jQuery is JavaScript.
2. That is not difficult. How can you implement this on your own ?
   Simply do 3 `<a>` tags each of them has an `id` and it depends on which one has been
   clicked. Then you just make an ajax call to get your information or simply rewrite the content of the div which is located in the centre.
3. So look how to implement `ajax` and `jQuery` in your code and you will be fine, it's not that hard to achieve  !

Comment: thanks for your answer, if i implemented this on my own, i would of probably done the same thing by changing the id's of the elements, but im trying to find out how the airbnb works.

Comment: why is that even necessary for you ? they did it the same way, its not hard.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the element id "search_type_photo" to see which script it's being referenced from...

[image: Airbnb]

Then clean up the script here - http://jsbeautifier.org/ so you can properly see how it's being called.

There's also an Airbnb API (unofficial) here - https://www.mashape.com/john-matt/airbnb